# problem in Text Alignment for label in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
 We have label with text in 2 lines.  In second line the text is not aligning exactly  to the left as in the first line. we had set property for the label as number of lines = 0.
```

for Ex:
   label.text = @"This is the text for the label."

In Result We are getting this as

```
This is the text
```

for the label.

But we want this as

```
This is the text
for the label.
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting the word wrap of button:

```
[label setNumberOfLines:0]
```

Edit:
just realised there's linebreak property of label, that should help

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```